# localhost [127.0.0.1] in email headers

Tags: email, sendmail

I'm using sendmail to send a very simple email from a text file. Here is the text file:

```
to:test@someaddress.com
from:admin@hostname.tld
subject:Testing

test test test
```

Which I send with:

```
sendmail -t < mail.txt
```

The server I am running sendmail from is hostname.tld. Here is /etc/hosts:

```
12.34.56.78     hostname hostname.tld
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Where hostname.tld is the fqdn of the server and 12.34.56.78 is the public IP of the server. /etc/hostname simply contains hostname.tld

When I receive the email, I get this header:

```
Received: from hostname.tld (hostname.tld [127.0.0.1])
```

I don't want 127.0.0.1, I want the public IP to be there, but I can't get sendmail to use it no matter what I do. I've also edited /etc/mail/sendmail.mc to have the line:

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `hostname.tld')dnl
```

But it does nothing.

I've read so many threads where people have a similar problem but nothing seems to resolve it. What can I do?

Comment: Why does this matter? Your network is obviously set up to route local mail locally, but any mail delivered to an external site will see your public IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Daemon mode vs. MSP

The annotation of the IP address you mentioned above is actually not a configuration of the `sendmail` server itself. If you look at a modern deployment of `sendmail` it's typically split into 2 components. The traditional server *(daemon mode)* and another server running in *mail submission program mode* (MSP). You can see this with a simple `ps` command:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep send
root     24488     1  0 21:10 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp    24504     1  0 21:10 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
```

The first line is sendmail in daemon mode, the second is sendmail in MSP mode. You can always tell them apart because most distros that ship sendmail make the MSP variant run as a special user with lesser privledges.  Here's it's running on my CentOS 5.x server as user `smmsp`.

**NOTE:** This is done to segregate the duties of handling mail submission (MSP) and mail delivery (daemon mode). Users connect to the MSP instance when they're sending mail with commands such as `mail` and `mailx` locally on the box.

When dealing with sendmail on a Red Hat based distro such as CentOS, the configuration files are located here: `/etc/mail`. There are 2 files that we're interested in for this modification:

- /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
- /etc/mail/submit.mc

The first file controls the daemon mode server, while the second file is meant for the MSP server.

Incidentally, these `*.mc` files aren't actual configuration files that the 2 servers use directly; in general `sendmail` configuration can be complicated. Given it's age and it's versatility it can be configured in a multitude of ways and so these `*.mc` files are pre-configuration files that get "compiled" into actual `sendmail` configuration files. The compiled versions of these files are also in the same directory:

- /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
- /etc/mail/submit.cf

It's usually wise to not make changes to these 2 files directly but rather make the changes through their corresponding `.mc` file. You typically edit the `.mc` files and then run the `make` command while inside the `/etc/mail` directory. Again this is a Red Hat-ism, to my knowledge, so another distro might make things differently.

*NOTE:** The `.mc` files are in a macro language called [M4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), so the tool to compiled them is of course called `m4`. You can manually compile these files with a command such as this:

```
$ m4 /etc/mail/submit.mc > /etc/mail/submit.cf
```

This is all that's going on with the fancy `make` and `Makefile` files that Red Hat provides in the `/etc/mail` directory.

#### Changes to submit.cf

So what changes do you need to make? The following line needs to be appended to the `submit.mc` file:

```
CLIENT_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Address=<your ip here>, Name=MTA')dnl
```

Be sure to add your IP where it says `<your ip here>`. Once you've made this change you'll need to regenerate your `submit.mc` file.

```
$ cd /etc/mail && make
```

Once you've regenerated the `.cf` file you'll need to restart `sendmail`:

```
$ /etc/init.d/sendmail restart
-or-
$ /etc/init.d/sendmail reload
```

#### Final product

After making the above change you'll be left with the following header. In this example my external IP address was 50.122.22.45, for example.

```
Return-Path: <root@mail.sdom.com>
Received: from mail.sdom.com (mail.sdom.com [50.122.22.45])
    by sdom.com (8.14.3/8.14.3) with ESMTP id r5J188Gx018193
    for <user@sdom.com>; Tue, 18 Jun 2013 21:08:08 -0400
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by mail.sdom.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Submit) id r5J15ua4018000;
    Tue, 18 Jun 2013 21:05:56 -0400
Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2013 21:05:56 -0400
Message-Id: <201306190105.r5J15ua4018000@mail.sdom.com>
to:user@sdom.com
from:admin@hostname.tld
subject:Testing
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-4.4 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,BAYES_00
    autolearn=ham version=3.2.5
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on mail.sdom.com
X-Greylist: Sender is SPF-compliant, not delayed by milter-greylist-4.0 (sdom.com [127.0.0.1]); Tue, 18 Jun 2013 21:08:09 -0400 (EDT)

test test test
```

## References

- [Red Hat documentation that discusses the setup of `sendmail`](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-email-mta-sendmail.html)
- [New Configuration File, submit.cf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0204/sendmail-122/index.html)

Comment: I don't think masquerading is what I am after.

Comment: @CameronBall - see my updates. Those 2 guys guilted me into digging into it.

Comment: What I did was similar to what you have posted but not quite the same. I'm marking you as accepted for the effort and additional info in your answer though.

Comment: @CameronBall - thanks, sorry I couldn't post this sooner. Didn't have time until tonight to research it more thoroughly. Damn day job 8-).

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution:

/etc/hosts :

```
12.34.56.78     hostname.tld
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

/etc/mail/submit.mc :

```
FEATURE(`msp', `[12.34.56.78]', `25')dnl
```

(originally it had 127.0.0.1 instead of my public IP)

/etc/mail/sendmail.mc :

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=12.34.56.78')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=12.34.56.78')dnl
```

(both of those lines originally had 127.0.0.1, changing it makes sendmail listen on your public IP instead of localhost).

Run the command:

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Reload sendmail:

```
service sendmail reload
```

After sending my test email with:

```
sendmail -t < mail.txt
```

The header I didn't like now says:

```
Received: from hostname.tld (hostname.tld [12.34.56.78])
```

And there's no mention of localhost or 127.0.0.1 anywhere in the headers